# Setting up Virtual Hosts in JBoss

Tags: ubuntu, coldfusion, jboss, jboss5.x

I am working on setting up a JBoss app server on my dev platform (Ubuntu 10.04 server with JBoss 5.1) for my coldfusion apps and can't seem to find the resources I am looking for for setting up the virtual hosts.  In the past I have used tomcat which I would setup a virtual host and use the context tag to point to the root of the working directory.  The directory was at /mnt/hgfs/ColdFusion/{project}/.  Right at the root of the project directory was where my codebase and WEB-INF was.

I would like to setup the same thing on JBoss, but everything seems give different ways to setup the virtual host and none seem to talk about a comparison of the context tag in Tomcat.

So is there a way to do the context tag from tomcat and what is the best way to setup virtual hosts in JBoss AS 5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup virtual hosts just like in Tomcat (in fact JBoss Web Service is sightly modified version of Tomcat).

You can find proper in yours profile in the `deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml`. You hvae just define in that file virtual hosts by defining `Host` tag.

Next you have to setup your application. Just create `jboss-web.xml` file and place it in application `WEB-INF` direcotry. In that file you have to bind your application with proper virtual host. It can looks like that:

```
<jboss-web>
   <context-root>/application_context</context-root>
   <virtual-host>virtual_host</virtual-host>
</jboss-web>
```

You can find some more info in that article: [Hosting Multiple Domains With JBoss](http://www.fusioncube.net/index.php/hosting-multiple-domains-with-jboss)

**Install application from outside direcotry**

You can add extra directory in which you can deploy your application (just like `deploy` directory).

You have to edit `conf/bootstrap/profile.xml` - you can find in your profile. Find property name `applicationURIs` and add extra dir:

```
<property name="applicationURIs">
    <list elementClass="java.net.URI">
        <value>${jboss.server.home.url}deploy</value>

        <!-- Below new directory do scan by JBoss AS -->
        <value>file:///nfs/applications</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

More info you can find here: [How to deploy my application in an external directory in JBoss-5](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowtodeploymyapplicationinanexternaldirectoryinJBoss-5)

Comment: Okay that answers part of my question, but how to I host the projects outside of the deploy directory?  I want them to be in /mnt/hgfs/Workspace/ColdFusion.